# Prove that $E(X) = P(X<a)E(X|X<a) + P(X\geq a)E(X|X\geq A)$

Tags: conditional-expectation

**Question**

While reading a [Wikipedia article on Markov's Inequality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Markov%27s_inequality), I came across the statement

$$E(X) = P(X<a)E(X|X<a) + P(X \geq a)E(X|X\geq A)$$

In the context of Markov's inequality, we are assuming $X$ is a non-negative r.v., but I don't think that's necessary for the statement to be true.

How do I prove this? I think I should use iterated expectation $E(E(X| ??)$ but I'm not exactly sure how. I'm used to things like $E(E(X|Y=y))$, not inequalities.

If it's relevant, I do not know measure theory yet.

**Solution**

The answer below is totally sufficient, but for a beginniner like me I felt it was useful to dive into the details. In case those details help anybody else, here they are:

We want to prove

$$E(X) = P(X<a)E(X | X<a) + P(X\geq a)E(X|X\geq a)$$

An answer below shows that

> \begin{align}
> E[X] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)dx \\
> &= \int_{-\infty}^a xf(x)dx +\int_a^\infty xf(x)dx \\
> &= \Pr(X<a)\int_{-\infty}^a \frac{xf(x)}{\Pr(X<a)}dx +\Pr(X\ge a)\int_a^\infty \frac{xf(x)}{\Pr(X\ge a)}dx \\
> &= \Pr(X<a)\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x\mid X<a)dx +\Pr(X\ge a)\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x\mid X\ge a)dx \\
> &= \Pr(X<a)E[X\mid X<a] +\Pr(X\ge a)E[X\mid X\ge a]
> \end{align}

Where $f(x)/\Pr(X<a)$ is the conditional pdf $f(x | X<a)$. The purpose of this extended answer is to investigate how this conditional probability works.

Typically we denote the conditional pdf for random variables $X,Y$ as

$$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_Y(y)$$

But what is the random variable $Y$ in this case? For convenience, denote $A^-=(-\infty,a)$ and $A^+=[a,\infty)$, then we define $L(X) = I_{A^-}(X)$ where $I_{A^-}$ is the indicator function on set $A^-$.

\begin{equation}
L(X) = I_{A^-}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $x\in (-\infty,a)$}\\
0 & \text{if $x\in [a,\infty)$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then

$$f_{X|L}(x|l) = \frac{f_{X,L}(x,l)}{f_L(l)}$$

where

\begin{equation}
f_L(l) = P(L(x)=l) =  
\begin{cases}
P(x\in A^-) & \text{if $l=1$}\\
P(x\in A^+) & \text{if $l=0$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

and $f_{X,L}(x,l)$ is defined such that

$$\Pr(X\in U,L\in V) = \sum_{l\in V}\int_{x\in U}f_{X,L}(x,l)dx $$

Note we must have

$$f_{X,L}(x,1) = 0 ~\text{  for  }~ x\in A^+$$

since by definition of the indicator function

$$P(X\in U\subset A^+ \land L=I_{A^-}(X)\in\{1\}) = 0$$

Also, by definition of the marginal pdf $f_L(l)$, we know that

$$\int_{x\in\mathbf{R}}f_{X,L}(x,1)dx = f_L(1) = P(X\in A^-) = P(X<a) = \int_{x<a}f(x)dx$$

This implies $f_{X,L}(x,1)=f(x)$ for $x<a$.

Similarly

$$f_{X,L}(x,0) = 0  ~\text{  for  }~ x\in A^-$$
since by definition

$$P(X\in U\subset A^-,L\in\{0\}) = 0$$

Again, by definition of the marginal pdf, we know

$$\int_{x\in\mathbf{R}}f_{X,L}(x,0)dx = f_L(0) = P(X\in A^+) = P(X\geq a) = \int_{x\geq a}f(x)dx$$

which implies $f_{X,L}(x,0) = f(x)$ for $x\geq a$.

Combining all this information, we see that

\begin{equation}
f_{X,L}(x,l) =  
\begin{cases}
f(x)I_{(-\infty,a)}(x) & \text{if $l=1$}\\
f(x)I_{[a,\infty)}(x) & \text{if $l=0$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Now we can give an explicit expression for $f_{X|L}(x|l)$:

\begin{equation}
f_{X|L}(x|l) = \frac{f_{X,L}(x,l)}{f_L(l)} =
\begin{cases}
& \frac{f(x)I_{(-\infty,a)}(x)}{P(X<a)} ~~\text{if $l=1$}\\
& \frac{f(x)I_{[a,\infty)}(x)}{P(X\geq a)} ~~\text{if $l=0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Essentially, the condition $X<a$ is represented with an indicator function
$(X<a)(x) = I_{(-\infty,a)}(x)$ and the new, conditioned random variable $X|X<a$ is given by $(X|X<a) = X I_{(-\infty,a)}(X)$. Using this notation, we could write

$$X|L \sim f_{X|L}(x|l) = f_{X|X<a}(x | (X<a)(x)) \sim (X|X<a)$$

Now we can make sense of the proof given at the beginning.

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^a xf(x)dx 
&= \Pr(X<a)\int_{-\infty}^a x\frac{f(x)}{\Pr(X<a)}dx\\
&= \Pr(X<a)\int_{-\infty}^a xI_{A^-}(x)\frac{f(x)I_{A^-}(x)}{\Pr(X<a)}dx\\
&= \Pr(X<a)\int_{-\infty}^a (x|x<a) f_{X|X<a}(x|1)dx\\
&= \Pr(X<a)E(X|X<a)
\end{align}

and similarly

\begin{align}
\int_a^\infty xf(x)dx
&= \Pr(X\geq a)\int_a^\infty x\frac{f(x)}{\Pr(X\geq a)}dx\\
&= \Pr(X\geq a)\int_a^\infty xI_{A^+}(x)\frac{f(x)I_{A^+}}{\Pr(X\geq a)}dx\\
&= \Pr(X\geq a)\int_a^\infty (x | x\geq a)f_{X|X\geq a}(x|1)dx \\
&= \Pr(X\geq a)E(X|X\geq a)
\end{align}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
E[X] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^a xf(x)dx +\int_a^\infty xf(x)dx \\
&= \Pr(X<a)\int_{-\infty}^a \frac{xf(x)}{\Pr(X<a)}dx +\Pr(X\ge a)\int_a^\infty \frac{xf(x)}{\Pr(X\ge a)}dx \\
&= \Pr(X<a)\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x\mid X<a)dx +\Pr(X\ge a)\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x\mid X\ge a)dx \\
&= \Pr(X<a)E[X\mid X<a] +\Pr(X\ge a)E[X\mid X\ge a]
\end{align}

Comment: I'm used to writing $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_Y(y)$ where $Y$ is a r.v., but how do we interpret $\text{Pr}(X<a)$ as the pdf/pmf of a r.v.? Can think of the indicator function $I_{(-\infty,a)}(x)$ as the discrete r.v. we are conditioning on?

Comment: So $f_{X|I_a}(x | I_a=1)=f_{X|X<a}(x|x<a) = f(x)/f_{I_a}(I_a(x)=1) = f(x)/\text{Pr}(X<a)$? This is my first time seeing something like this, I'm trying to make sure I understand it!

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea.  Notice also that the conditioning changes the support; i.e., $f_{X\mid X<a}$ is zero for $X \ge a$.

Comment: As an aside, in a measure theory setting you could have a nicer proof starting from the fact $\Pr(A)=\Pr(A \cap (B \cup B^C)) = \Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(A\cap B^C)=\Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)+\Pr(A\mid B^C)\Pr(B^C)$.

Comment: Hi again, I edited my answer to really delve into the details of conditioning the random variable $X$ on the condition or indicator function $I_{(-\infty,a)}(x)$. I'm sure you're busy -- but if by chance you get a moment to peruse my edit, I would love to hear your opinion on whether it makes any sense. Thank you again for the nice proof you provided

Comment: I looked it over quickly and I'd say you're working through the details correctly.  One other aside is that a fundamental connection between probability and expectation is that for an indicator function $I_A$, $E[I_A]=\Pr(A)$.